# How can i pass one module variable to another module in python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I will try below code but code.

First module

a.py

```
class A:
    def run:
        self.x=20
```

Second module

b.py

```
 from a import A
 class B:
     def run:
          c= a.A()
          c.run()
          Print c.x
```

But it’s giving me error.

```
 typeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Comment: This error is thrown because in class A you need to declare the arguments: def run(self, x)

Comment: Hi tombam, Thanks for replay. Can you explain more using example? so i can resolve this problem.

Comment: Tom literally gave you the exact solution. This is basic Python; you should go and do a tutorial. Also, you have not posted real code; this wouldn't even compile.

Comment: Cross-posted as http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/171658/how-can-i-pass-set-cookies-one-module-and-get-another-module-in-python

Comment: Any another way to pass variable one module to another module in python like (Cookies and session)

Answer (score 1):

This error is thrown because in class A you need to declare the arguments:

```
def run(self, x):
```

You also need to pass these arguments in b.py with :

```
c.run('x-goes-here')
```

As Daniel mentioned in the comments, this is fairly trivial python (although confusing for the beginner). I suggest you try the python 'classes' section on the Codecademy website.

Comment: When I pass arguments in Importtool('a').

Its give me below error :

 thing = Importtool('a')

  File "C:/Users/n/.qgis2/python/plugins\Importtool\Import_tool.py", line 117, in __init__
    self.toolbar = self.iface.addToolBar(u'Importtool')

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'addToolBar'

Comment: Edit your question with the relevant code and error and I will do my best to answer, your comment is not clear.

Answer (score 0):

a.py

```
class A:
def run(self):
    self.x = 20
```

b.py

```
from a import A
class B:
    def run(self):
        c = A()
        c.run()
        print c.x

b = B()
b.run()
```